# Reduce controls that count how many bombs are in "KMines" game

Tags: android, math

Many of you know the game for the computer called "KMines", I create the app for the mobile phone with Android Studio.
The game works, but not very well becouse the controls that count how many bombs it has around the selected box is too many and it lag.
[image: MY MAP]
I need help, these are my controls if the the box haven't a bomb inside. I'm looking for a way to reduce them.

```
if(mat_prato[y][x] == 0){

                        if(y == 0 && x == 0){           //The four corners of the map
                            if(mat_prato[y][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else  if(y == 0 && x == 9){
                            if(mat_prato[y][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x- 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else  if(y == 9 && x == 9){
                            if(mat_prato[y][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x- 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else  if(y == 9 && x == 0){
                            if(mat_prato[y][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x+ 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else  if(y == 0 && 0 < x && x < 9){       // The sides of the map
                            if(mat_prato[y][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else  if(y == 9 && 0 < x && x < 9){
                            if(mat_prato[y][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else  if(x == 0 && 0 < y && y < 9){
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else  if(x == 9 && 0 < y && y < 9){
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        } else if(0 < x && x < 9 && 0 < y && y < 9){      // The other cell in the center
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y - 1][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x - 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                            if(mat_prato[y + 1][x + 1] == 9)
                                c = c + 1;
                        }

                        if(c == 0){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 10;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.empty;
                        } else if(c == 1){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 1;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.one;
                        } else if(c == 2){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 2;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.two;
                        } else if(c == 3){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 3;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.three;
                        } else if(c == 4){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 4;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.four;
                        } else if(c == 5){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 5;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.five;
                        } else if(c == 6){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 6;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.six;
                        } else if(c == 7){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 7;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.seven;
                        } else if(c == 8){
                            mat_prato[y][x] = 8;
                            mThumb[position] = R.drawable.eight;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Use a for loop. Also, while the code can certainly be cleaned up (by using a loop), the loop will take about the same time - so this is not the cause for any slowness.

Comment: how? expain a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a loop to iterate over the neighbors of a cell, instead of gigantic if-statements. The loops may not be faster, but no programmer would use anything else for this problem: they are much, much simpler.

Let us assume that you have this method defined:

```
// returns true only if bomb at x,y; and false for "outside" or "no bomb"
private boolean isBomb(int x, int y)
```

Now you can define this other method that uses it:

```
private int countBombsAround(int x, int y) {
    int deltas[][] = { 
         {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, 
         { 0, -1}, /*skip*/ { 0, 1},
         { 1, -1}, { 1, 0}, { 1, 1}};
    int bombs = 0;
    for (int delta[] : deltas) {
        if (isBomb(x+delta[1], y+delta[0]) bombs ++;
    }
    return bombs;
}
```

And this method works for all valid (and even invalid!) x,y positions in the game. It is also much shorter, and once you know it works (by testing it), you should not need to ever change it again. Win-win!.

Note that the above code does not look in the center square - you should have checked that via `isBomb` first. Also, there are many, many ways to write a similar loop. The important point is that, if you ever find yourself writing similar things over and over again in a program, *there is a better way to do it*.

Comment: Thanks, this evening I try to doscrivo it